# Call JavaScript function from UIViewController class in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to call javascript function from one of my view controller class,

here is my code snippet i have tried, but it is not working :(

Code in my `ViewController`

```
- (NSString *)MyMehtod{
    JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
    JSValue *function = context[@"ProfilePicFunction"];
  [context evaluateScript: [self loadJsFromFile]]; //crashes here EXC_BAD_ACESS
     JSValue* result = [function callWithArguments:@[[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/ProfilePic.png"]]];
    NSLog(@"result = %@",result);
}

- (NSString *)loadJsFromFile
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"app" ofType:@"js"]; //path returns here as nil
        NSString *jsScript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; //jsScript returns here as nil
        return jsScript;
    }
```

Code in `app.js` file

```
function ProfilePicFunction(ProfilePicPath){
     var d= new Date();

    var userFullPath = ProfilePicPath+"?"+d.getTime();

    $("#userImg").attr("src",userFullPath);
}
```

Location of `app.js`
[image]
**Please help and thanks in advance!!**

Comment: Have you checked js directory is in your bundle? From your errors it sounds like its not.

Comment: also tried `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"app" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@"js"];`    it returns path now instead of nil but javascript function is not getting called :(

Comment: Add some debug NSLog statements for each line of code and post it. Otherwise hard to know what is going wrong. Also, does app.js depend on other javascript. If so you will have to load all the supporting it needs first?

Comment: I get the feeling you may be way of track here. app.js is running jquery code. You are going to need a JSContext onto a UIWebView or other JSVirtualMachine with a loaded web page that has pulled in jquery and whatever DOM you are trying to manipulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the order of your code :

1) First you have to evaluate the script:

```
[context evaluateScript: [self loadJsFromFile]];
```

2) Then get the name of the function from the context

```
JSValue *function = context[@"ProfilePicFunction"];
```

Comment: you will not get result because you return nothing from the method , i think this might help : http://hayageek.com/execute-javascript-in-ios/  ... you can change the implementation of the method to sum operation for example and check if your JS code was correct or not

Comment: Thnk you for the code `3rd` point  is helpful for me `(Access JavaScript functions and execute them in Objective-C)`  but the my problem is my javascript function is located in `app.js` file :( how to aceess that file and executethat code in objective c?

Answer (score -1):

```
- (NSString *)loadJsFromFile{
     NSString* js = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"app" ofType:@"js"]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     return js;
}
```